# Try Catch around a return statement

Tags: .net, exception, return

Saw an interesting piece of code recently, and my mind made a snap judgement that it'd be like something I'd see on TDWTF.

However, before I start changing code I didn't write in case there is a reason for it, I figured I'd ask here.

```
public function SomeFunction() As SomeType
    Dim someResult As New SomeType

    // Some code here, where some result can't become nothing.

    try
         return someResult
    catch ex As Exception
         // Some logging code

         return Nothing
    end try
end function
```

My first impression is that it would be impossible for a simple return with no other operations on the same line to throw an exception, and that this code is unnecessary.

However no compiler warning about unreachable code, so it did have me wondering if it's at all possible.

Is it? If so, what would be a case it could happen?

Comment: there isn't a good reason for that. maybe just a typo.

Comment: That's a possibility, perhaps there was at once more code in the Try block that got removed and the developer didn't think to remove the whole try/catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No I don't think it's possible. The compiler simply doesn't know that this statement cannot fail, so it cannot issue a warning.

Answer (score 1):

If SomeResult is a property, there's no reason to believe it couldn't throw an exception.  Even if it's a field of "this", there are ways that methods can be invoked with "this" being a null reference.  To be sure, most such cases would indicate a sufficiently severe problem that the method shouldn't try to muddle on by returning null itself, but it is at least possible for the catch to execute.